# count grouped records by ID and show as weekly with day/week outputted

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table in which I have to count total records assigned to each USER by weekly (monday to sunday).

Table BooksIssued

```
BOOKID      USER    DATE
 1            A        20211001
 2            A        20211002
 3            A        20211003
 4            A        20211004
 5            B        20211009
 6            C        20211008
 7            C        20211008
```

20211001 is friday.

output of sql query is as follows, the WEEKDATE column shows the week end date (i.e sunday)

```
WEEKCOUNT     USER     WEEKDATE
 3            A        10/03
 1            A        10/10
 1            B        10/10
 2            C        10/10
```

I am unable to get the date in output containing day, as grouping is done based on user and week part of date. Please suggest on getting above output.
I am using vertica DB.
Below is sample query i tried (though i could not get the day part of date)

```
SELECT USER, date_part('WEEK', date)) as WEEKDATE
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE >= timestampadd(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, date('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'), date(sysdate)), date('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'))
                AND  DATE <  timestampadd(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, date('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'), date(sysdate)) + 1, date('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'))
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WEEKCOUNT,
FROM   BOOKSISSUED
GROUP BY USER, date_part('WEEK', date)
```

when i add date_part('DAY', date) in select clause, i get error as its not in group by.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
WITH
-- your input ...
indata(BOOKID,USR,DT) AS (
          SELECT 1,'A',DATE '20211001'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'A',DATE '20211002'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'A',DATE '20211003'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'A',DATE '20211004'
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'B',DATE '20211009'
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'C',DATE '20211008'
UNION ALL SELECT 7,'C',DATE '20211008'
)
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS         week_count
, usr 
, TO_CHAR(
    DATE_TRUNC('WEEK',dt) + INTERVAL '6 DAYS'
  , 'MM/DD'
  )  AS trcweek
FROM indata
GROUP BY 2,3 
ORDER BY 2,3 
;
 week_count | usr | trcweek 
------------+-----+---------
          3 | A   | 10/03
          1 | A   | 10/10
          1 | B   | 10/10
          2 | C   | 10/10
```

Comment: Thanks. The trcweek should just show 03/10 (i.e day and month; which in turn gives the week ending)

Comment: I just edited my answer - modifying the original expression for `trcweek`: I put a `TO_CHAR()` function around it. Just swap `MM` with `DD` in the format string if you want it the English/French way rather than the American way ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the sql query syntax.

In the `SELECT` clause second column and group by clause second column

```
SELECT USER, date_part('WEEK', date) as WEEKDATE,
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE >= timestampadd(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, date('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'), date(sysdate)), date('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'))
            AND  DATE < timestampadd(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, date('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'), date(sysdate)) + 1, date('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'))
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WEEKCOUNT
FROM BOOKSISSUED
GROUP BY USER, date_part('WEEK', date)
```